# efficiently converting for model.fit

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm struggling in loading data into model.fit efficiently. My code creates `training_data` object with `samples` and `values`. Samples is a standard python list of objects of `tf.Tensor` class. Values is a list of integers.

When running

`model.fit(training_data.samples, training_data.values, epochs=10)`

I get an error

`ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})`

I can get this two work, by pre-converting it all to numpy arrays like this:

```
s, v = np.asarray(training_data.samples), np.asarray(training_data.values)
model.fit(s, v, epochs=10)
```

However this is impossibly slow. Loading data and very heavy preprocessing (signal chunking, fft, etc. etc.) takes about a minute and then just the data conversion with 1800 samples this part hangs for an hour and I lose patience before actual learning starts. Tensors's shape is (94, 257) so nothing big.

So what's an efficient way to pass data to model.fit, given that I already have it in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is just a suggestion but try using a generator object from tf.keras.utils.Sequence but this also depends on what type of data you are using?

You can look at the example here:
[https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly)

I implemented my own here you can check it out:
https://github.com/edwin-19/custom_keras_generator/blob/master/notebooks/Model%20Comparison.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

For me it's a common error when I use the wrong input format (typically when I pass a list).

Try to convert only training_data.values to a numpy array or a tensor if it's a list.

As pinpointed in the documentation (x, y, validation_data,..) have a limited number of accepted inputs, i.e. numpy array and tensor:
[model.fit](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)